# SE keeps loading because qa.sockets.stackexchange.com is switching protocols

Tags: bug, web-sockets

At my work computer, I sometimes get this weird situation where the quarter circle in the Chrome Tab keeps spinning. I've checked the network activity, and it shows that `qa.sockets.stackexchange.com` is stuck in *status 101: "Switching protocols"*.

Request headers:

```
Request URL:wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:101 Switching Protocols
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Upgrade
Cookie:__qca=P0-1108019536-1390549277823; _ga=GA1.2.1508710413.1390549278; __utma=27693923.1508710413.1390549278.1410953797.1411112642.26; __utmc=27693923; __utmz=27693923.1411112642.26.26.utmcsr=codereview.stackexchange.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/questions/63283/password-validation-in-java
Host:qa.sockets.stackexchange.com
Origin:http://stackoverflow.com
Pragma:no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits, x-webkit-deflate-frame
Sec-WebSocket-Key:WO8EICMtuCNzW5AbSKZqAQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Upgrade:websocket
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
Response Headers
Connection:Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept:OH1RtIPp8BBRIXpL+UnOk95nrFc=
Upgrade:websocket
```

This happens all the time, although it doesn't always get indicated by the spinning circle. What is this `qa.sockets.stackexchange.com`, and why does it get stuck on switching protocols?

Comment: I think it's normal that the request is on "pending" since it's an active WebSocket. I don't get a spinning wheel, perhaps there's a different request that's stuck?

Comment: @Stijn I don't always get a spinning wheel, but when I check the dev console, the request remains on 101 switching protocols. I don't really mind it, but it's just a little bit annoying if it happens with a spinning wheel because that usually means the website isn't loading.

Comment: A web socket that is in state 101 switching protocols is a happy web socket. Something else is amiss.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs: Now check the dev console when you **don't** get a spinning wheel. The request will still remain on 101 switching protocols...

Comment: I see. I'm not that experienced with web sockets, so I don't know what they usually indicate. The weird thing is that I currently have Stack overflow homepage open on 2 different tabs. 1 is stuck in the spinning wheel, even after refresh, one is not and remains that way even after refresh.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs: In Chrome, closing and reoping the tab usually helps. Certain versions of Chrome have some issues with pipelining, it seems.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so it's not a problem with SO, but with my browser? Chrome says it's up to date though.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs: I come across it with Chrome from time to time; not lately though. Could be an interaction with the network. But not a problem with Stack Overflow, no.

Comment: Seeing the same issue in my browser today (Chrome) and I see it pretty regularly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at the last stage of a websocket negotiation. The protocol is switched after the 101 status. It means that part of the websocket handshake *worked*. Websockets remain open for the duration of the page, so the behaviour you are seeing is **normal**. You'll see the same status on pages that do work.

If you click on the *Frames* tab (next to the *Headers* tab you got those headers from) you'll find a series of green entries showing what info has been received over the socket.

The spinning ball is almost certainly **not** caused by the websocket. For me, it is usually a connection to gravatar.com or i.stack.imgur.com that is hanging. Closing the affected Chrome tab usually resolves this issue. In other words, this is a Chrome issue, not a Stack Overflow issue.